# I have been having issues connecting my sanity schema to react program

Tags: reactjs, sanity

Line 40:1:  Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to Sanity, this is an eslint warning. It's telling you to set a name before exporting.

eg. for an object, instead of:

```js
export default {
  key: 'value'
}
```

You need to name it first:

```js
const someObj = {
  key: 'value'
}

export default someObj;
```

Can read more about it here: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md